# html visibility style doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an odd problem.
I have button, "NextButton" that i want to hide initially but then when a checkbox is clicked, it should appear.
Below code doesn't work and it doesn't give any error. I've tested it on IE9 and FireFox 13
I searched other questions but couldn't find the problem that i am having...

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
        function enableNext() {
            alert("clicked");

            var s1 = document.getElementsByName("NextButton");
            s1.style.visibility = "visible";
        } 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="submit" name="NextButton" value="Next" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
<input type="checkbox" onClick="enableNext()" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't give any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array is returned in your code and you are applying style to an array. Change it to the code below.

```
 function enableNext() {
            alert("clicked");

            var s1 = document.getElementsByName("NextButton")[0];//Get the first and only button in your case
            s1.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByName returns an array of matched elements, you have to loop over it and change the style of individual items in the array. You can use jQuery to handle it easily `$("[name='NextButton']").css("visibility", "visible")` or if you want to use css `display` property you can use `$("[name='NextButton']").show()` or `.hide()`. Additionally if you don't want to use jQuery you can just use an id and instead of using `getElementsByName` use `getElementById`, it will return a single element that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `id` in HTML element and then `document.getElementById()`. This will give exact matched element.

```
<script language="javascript">
        function enableNext() {
            alert("clicked");

            var s1 = document.getElementById("NextButton");
            s1.style.visibility = "visible";
        } 
</script>
```

`<input type="submit" id="NextButton" name="NextButton" value="Next" style="visibility:hidden;"/`>

Comment: @user156144: Did you add `id` to button ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try using css instead javascript alone.

Try using

```
document.getElementsByName("NextButton")[0];
```